# Does a VPN encryption get stripped from data during cellular transmission?

Tags: network, vpn, 5g

These phones have all the generations of connectivity but “only use 5G.”

On top of that the new GPS Satellite iPhone feature for people that get lost does a VPN protocol work for that, what about downgrade attacks, IMSI catchers, frequency/sdr sniffers?

It seems like multiple questions but they are similar concerns.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a VPN encryption get stripped from data during cellular transmission?

Generally, no.

IPsec or SSL VPN sit on top of the underlying network and are not changed during transport.

'Stripping VPN encryption' implies terminating the encrypted tunnel. That requires knowledge of the used keys which a network provider usually does not have. Additionally, most tunnels use private addressing for the inner IPv4 packets which a public network cannot route.

Your other questions about downgrade attacks, IMSI catchers and sniffing are too broad to be answered and may likely be off topic (for being about a network not under your control). None of those attacks can break a VPN connection if it's properly set up.

Of course, any network can (try to) detect payloads and filter any amount of what it detects. Whether that's legal or even required depends on local legislation.